# Find an exact match of a number into a text string with random letters and numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have only numbers in Sheet2 in col.B starting with B2: 81, 102 (in B3), 104 (in B4), etc, and in Sheet1 in col.A starting with A2, mixed text with numbes with no logical place text like: abc813bnm 12mn (in A2), fgh 81lkj 45ol (in A3), ert1042hji (in A4), and so on. I need to search each number from col.B/Sheet2 in col.A/Sheet1 and write in is an exact match on the same row in col.Q let's say. he exact match of first no.81 is in A3 (fgh 81lkj 45ol), but not in A2 (abc813bnm 12mn) where it is inside of 813 string. In my code 81 (and not only) it is "found" and in the cell with 81 and in a cell with 813, and I do not want that:

Sub SearchLCL()

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim LCL1 As String
Dim LCL2 As String
'Dim answer As String
Dim c As Range
Dim counter As Long
Dim totalLCL1 As Long
Dim totalLCL2 As Long

counter = 2

'Sheets("MailElibLCL").Select 'Sheet2
'Sheets("lucrari 2017").Select 'Sheet1

totalLCL2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
totalLCL1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'totalLCL2 = N
'totalLCL1 = N3

For I = 2 To totalLCL2
'answer = Worksheets("hedis1").Range("h" & counter).Value
LCL2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).Value
'LCL2 = "=MID(Worksheets.Sheet1.Range(""A"" & counter),SEARCH(LCL1,Worksheets.Sheet1.Range(""A"" & counter)),LEN(LCL1))"
k = "Q" & counter
For j = 2 To totalLCL1
    LCL1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & j).Value

     If InStr(1, LCL2, LCL1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print LCL1

'If LCL1 = LCL2 Then
        'If answer = "Yes" Then
            For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(k)

                'c.Value = Mid(LCL2, Search(LCL1, LCL2), Len(LCL1))
                'c.Formula = "=MID(LCL2,INSTR(LCL1,LCL2),LEN(LCL1))"
                'c.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 6 ' Change the number to match the desired color.
                c.Value = LCL1 '& vbLf & Date   'Now (si ora minute secunde)
                'c.Interior.Color = 5296210 ' Change the number to match the desired color.

            Next c
        'End If
    'End If
    End If
    Next j
counter = counter + 1
Next I
```

'Else
   'Call ScrieMailElib
   'End If

On Error GoTo 0

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

End Sub

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a formula, this example is checking for 30 in abc30ded435wdfq345 for example

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(30,J16,1)),"No Match","Match")`

Not sure if I fully understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can work this into your code. It uses regular expressions. It's a surprisingly lengthy pattern to find a simple number.

This just looks for the number 81.

```
Sub x()

Dim oRgx As Object, rCell As Range

Set oRgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With oRgx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([^0-9]|^)81([^0-9]|$)"
    For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If .Test(rCell) Then MsgBox rCell.Address
    Next rCell
End With

End Sub
```

[image]